# Unity Mobile Control for 2 players (Counting touches)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to implement controls for 2 players on one screen

Here is a code:

```
if (playerNum == 1) {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > 0 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width / 4) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > Screen.width / 4 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width / 2) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.back * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > Screen.width / 2 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width * 3 / 4) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.back * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > Screen.width * 3 / 4 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like schematic:

[image]

With

> if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
>           for (int i = 0; **i < 1**; i++)

I  can get only one tap, not only for red or green zone, but for full screen. If value is higher, **i < 5** (for example), I can hold 4 fingers only in one zone and rotate 4 times faster. 
How can I change the code to count only one tap for each zone?

Comment: In your picture, where are users supposed to be able to click ?

Comment: There are 4 zones for 2 players, you can click everywhere, but i need to handle one click from one zone, not more

Comment: And you need to know which zone and position in zone user has clicked, right ?

Comment: No i just need to make rotation, when tapping a zone. But currently i can hold X fingers in one zone and rotation will be X time faster. I need to rotate with same speed always, no matter ther is 4 or 1 finger

Comment: See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html to know when user touches and releases, then act accordingly on what behavior you want.

Comment: What if you used buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have created 4 variable: AZone,BZone,CZone,DZone. Now i can control every touch. In my example I'm rotating only if AZone equals 1. It works pretty good, exactly what i needed. Thanks for helping me in solving this problem.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
    AZone = 0;
    BZone = 0;
    //Debug.Log (Input.touchCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
        if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > 0 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width / 4) {
            AZone += 1;
            if (AZone == 1) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            //Debug.Log (AZone);
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch (i).position.x > Screen.width / 4 && Input.GetTouch (i).position.x < Screen.width / 2) {
            BZone += 1;
            if (BZone == 1) {
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.back * 300f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any emulator at hand but I believe the following should work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 300.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        var w = Screen.width / 4.0f;
        var h = Screen.height;
        var r1 = new Rect(w * 0, 0.0f, w, h);
        var r2 = new Rect(w * 1, 0.0f, w, h);
        var r3 = new Rect(w * 2, 0.0f, w, h);
        var r4 = new Rect(w * 3, 0.0f, w, h);

        var t1 = Input.GetTouch(0);
        var tc = Input.touchCount;

        if (tc == 1 && t1.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            var pos = t1.position;
            var dir = Vector3.zero;

            if (r1.Contains(t1.position))
                dir = Vector3.back;

            if (r2.Contains(pos))
                dir = Vector3.forward;

            transform.Rotate(dir * Speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can var t1 = Input.GetTouch(0); only if Input.touchCount > 0. I've added it, but still doesnt work